# Automatic deploy of some branches with Travis CI

Tags: deployment, travis-ci

I now how to deploy and I know how to only build some branches, but is there any way to build all (or some number of) branches and only deploy the builds for the master branch?

Something like a deploy white list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found in the docs that if you are using a `deploy` section to do your deployments, you can do conditional releases with the `on:` property and specify a branch:

```
deploy:
  ...
  on:
    branch: master
```

[Here is the link to the documentation.](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#Conditional-Releases-with-on%3A)

Hope this helps!